# Getting ZeroMQ up and running on Windows 10

Tags: java, python-3.x, windows, zeromq

I'm trying to get ZeroMQ up and running on Windows 10, my aim to use ZeroMQ/flatbuffers to exchange structured messages between a Java process and a Python process. I'm find the ZeroMQ website terse and it's not clear to me how to simply get ZeroMQ libs built with ease, the steps described always result in an error of some sort.

Can anyone point me towards a simple set of instructions to get the libraries generated that actually works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are faster options

- [Jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) pure Java ZeroMQ
- use [linux sub system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) for Windows 10 with Ubuntu

Building the libs:

1. download and install Community Edition with package "Individual components">"C++ CMake tools for Windows"
2. download latest [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/releases) release as `.zip`
3. unzip
4. open Visual Studio
5. choose "Open a local folder" and select ZeroMQ folder
6. right click *CMakeLists.txt* > *CMake settings for ZeroMQ* > *x86-Release*
7. above the project tree select "CMake targets view" from "Toggle between Solution and Folder views"
8. right click *ZeroMQ Project* > *Build All*
9. your user profile folder will contain a folder *CMakeBuilds* which contains the build results

Comment: Thanks, I've gone for the JeroMQ option. Works a treat !